# How to make my YouTube video be able to play at 2x without getting stuck?

Tags: youtube, video

I have uploaded a YouTube video which when played in 1.75x onwards, the video appears stuck but the audio plays.

Why is this behavior seen? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found this issue happens if the original video is created or shot at less than 40 or 50 frames per second (fps). In my case my video was shot at 30 FPS which caused this issue on mobile phone screens which i tested on my android phone.

A fix is : to shoot the video at 50 to 60 fps and not lesser.